# Is there a way to emulate UseLayoutRounding in WPF with .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

For installation reasons, I'd like to use 3.5 in my application.  The only feature that I would be lacking is UseLayoutRounding, which worked very nicely with my custom controls.  Is there a way to emulate UseLayoutRounding in 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact requirements, `SnapsToDevicePixels="true"` may be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still need a workaround, here's the link, look for the Thomas Levesque comment:
http://tech.pro/tutorial/1062/wpfs-most-important-property-uselayoutrounding

> We had a similar issue at work in a WPF 3.5 project, and eventually we solved it by setting RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode to NearestNeighbor and displaying the images in their original size (Stretch=None)

```
<Image Source="/namespace;component/Resources/image.png" Stretch="None" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
```

This would not solve problems with DPI on different systems though.